# Bindy Camel decimal format

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I am trying to write decimal pattern for Camel Bindy so it formats decimal number in this way ( it removes ".0" for integer numbers ):
1.1333333 - 1.1333333,
1.0 - 1,
-2.0 - -2,

For each field I have different precision. I have managed to create something like that:

```
@DataField(pos = 12, columnName = "", precision = 16, decimalSeparator = ".", pattern = "#.#")
```

It converts in this way:
1.1333333 - 1.1333333,
0.123456789123456 - 0.123456789123456,
1.0 - 1.0,
-2.0 - -2.0,

Any one can help. I could not find any examples on google.